# How do i pass my returned json string to different textbox

Tags: asp.net

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static string Get_OtherBillInfo(string EntryID)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Bill_Report"] == null)
    {
            return null;
    }

    List<TenementNotePrintedModel> BillReport = (List<TenementNotePrintedModel>)HttpContext.Current.Session["Bill_Report"];
    TenementNotePrintedModel model = BillReport.Find(ct => ct.EntryID.Equals(int.Parse(EntryID)));
    JavaScriptSerializer h = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string str = h.Serialize(model);
    return str;

}
```

=============================

```
 $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: 'BillReoprt_PayerID.aspx/Get_OtherBillInfo',
                  data: JSON.stringify({ 'EntryID':EntryID}),
                  dataType: 'json',
                  async: false,
                  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                  success: function (response)
                  {
                      if (response.d != "")
                      {



                      }

                  },
                error: function (response)
                {
                      var r = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
                      alert("Message: " + r.Message);
                      alert("StackTrace: " + r.StackTrace);
                      alert("ExceptionType: " + r.ExceptionType);
                  }

              });
          }
```

================================My returned Data from json is this============

```
{"d":"{\"EntryID\":76556,\"AssmtNoNew\":1571,\"OwnerID\":16053,\"AssmtNoNew09\":null,\"PropertyID\":15117,\"PID\":\"C-649387/ ALICE MPEREH  AND BROS AND SIS - \",\"oPID\":\"649387\",\"HouseNbr\":\"B105\",\"BatchNo\":null,\"FullName\":\"ALICE MPEREH  AND BROS AND SIS ()\",\"GeneratedBy\":null,\"BusinessName\":\"\",\"ElectoralID\":null,\"ElectoralArea\":null,\"EvaluationCode\":null,\"strCode\":null,\"AreaOff\":\"WESTERN REGION\",\"LgaName\":null,\"ZoneName\":null,\"AgencyCode\":null,\"LGA\":\"SHC\",\"AREAID\":null,\"StrName\":\"NEW EFFIA\",\"ShopNo\":null,\"Arr_Chargeable\":\"Y\",\"RevCode\":\"2021602\",\"Descr\":\"GROUND RENT(2nd Class Residential -Plot Up to 0.25 acre) 2021602\",\"propAddr\":\"B105, NEW EFFIA, WESTERN REGION\",\"ADDRESS\":\"B108, NEW EFFIA, WESTERN REGION\",\"FDescr\":\"\",\"PropertyStatus\":\"UnAssessed\",\"ArrearsPeriod\":\"\",\"Ratable\":0,\"ImpostRate\":0,\"AmtDue\":70,\"MinRate\":70,\"Arrears\":0,\"ArrearsInt\":0,\"Paymt\":0,\"OtherCharges\":0,\"TotalDue\":70,\"PayDate\":null,\"pAssmtYr\":null,\"AssmtYr\":\"2012\",\"OldAssessmtRef\":null,\"AssessmtRef\":null,\"DepoSlip\":\"12/16053\",\"DatePrinted\":null,\"BillStatus\":null,\"BatchPrint\":null}"}
```

Thanks for your help...

Comment: What is your question? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you intend to do;
 inside success:

```
if (response.d != "") {
    var responseObject = JSON.parse(response);

    $("#YourTextBoxId").val(responseObject.d.BusinessName); 

}
```

or

```
$("#<%= YourServerTextBox.UniqueId %>").val(responseObject.d.BusinessName);
```